# Proof system soundness and completeness

Tags: proof-explanation

Is a proof system with the single rule of inference {}⊢ φ for all φ **sound**, **complete**, **both**, or **neither**?

I think it is sound but I feel like there is a caveat, am I wrong?

Comment: Soundness means intuitively that it can't prove any false things; does the rule you've described look sound? Put another way, does it let you deduce something from $\{\}$ that you shouldn't be able to?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! You put me on the right track :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's complete if anyone interested...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1297188)

Comment: I'm the author and this is the answer to the question